# How can I get a programmatically created dragover event to work (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, dom-events

I have several drag and drop functions. I want to make certain drop targets unavailable during `dragover` based on the properties of the element being dragged over them without using global variables. However, I have not been able to find a way to access the properties of the element being dragged in the function handling the `dragover` event. I can access both during the drag function using `document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);` to get the drop target. I created the `dragover` event programmatically from within the drag function and attached it to the element being dragged over, but it won't work. What am I doing wrong?

```html
 
  <script>
    function allowDrop(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }

   

    function DragTest(event) {
      let DTest = new DataTransfer();
      DTest.effectAllowed = "all";
      let DraggedOverEle = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
      let DragOverVar = new DragEvent('dragover', {
        cancelable: true,
        bubbles: true,
        composed: true,
        dataTransfer: DTest
      });

      //eventually wrap allowDrop in if(event.target.someProperty != DraggedOverEle.someProperty){}
      allowDrop(DragOverVar);

    }
  </script>

<body>

  <!--allows drop but I can't access the element being dragged over-->
  <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <!--doesn't allow drop-->
  <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)"></div>
  <div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)"></div>
  <br>
  <img id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondrag="DragTest(event)">

</body>
```

I logged the event from `allowDrop` and noticed the `dataTransfer.effectAllowed` property was `none` in the programmatically created `dragover` events and `all` for the ones that are called from the element normally. I tried to adjust that by adding a `DataTransfer()` to my event specifying `effectAllowed='all'` but when the event is logged it still comes up as `none`.

Comment: Please create a [mre]. Reducing the amount of text and just simply state what isn;t working as expected might clean up your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function onDragOver(event) {
    console.log('Dragging over', event.target.id)
    event.target.classList.add('dragged-over')
    event.preventDefault();
}
function onDragLeave(event) {
    event.target.classList.remove('dragged-over');
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  let data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  console.log(data, 'is dropped on', ev.target.id);  
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  ev.target.classList.remove('dragged-over');
}
```

```css
body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: 1;
}

#div1, #div2, #div3 {
    width: 33%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background: transparent;
}

img { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 125px;
}

.dragged-over {
    background: green !important;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 50px !important;
}
```

```html
<!--allows drop but I can't access the element being dragged over-->
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="onDragOver(event)" ondragleave="onDragLeave(event)"></div>

<!--doesn't allow drop-->
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)"></div>
<div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)"></div>

<img id="drag1" src="https://placehold.co/100?text=Drag%20Me!" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
```

Comment: This isn’t exactly what I’m looking for but I could make it work. Instead of applying a special class to the drop zone I could apply it to the element being dragged at dragstart and access it by class name in the dragover function. Thanks! Things would be so much easier if we could just access the dataTransfer set in dragstart on dragover or if one of the dragover event properties would point to the object being dragged.

Comment: I would but I’m so new here I don’t have the 15 reputation points needed to vote yet. Sorry